# Modify color QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, text, colors, qtreewidget

How to change the color of every text in QTreeWidget (item text, name of column)?

In fact, I have a QTreeWidget inside a GroupBox and when I have modified the styleSheet of my GroupBox, this was inherited in the QTreeWidget. So, I have modified the styleSheet in the QTreeWidget with `color: rgb(0, 0, 0);`, but when I execute the application, the color is the same as the GroupBox and not the stylesheet of QTreeWidget (whereas it is modified in the designer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a stylesheet for your QGroupBox do it like this:

```
QGroupBox{color: red;}
```

This way your QTreeWidget will ignore this stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

YOu could try using [QTreeWIdgetItem:SetForeground](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setForeground)

or to set the background you could use

```
  item->setBackground(column, QBrush());
```

[qsetheaders](https://geocap.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ref/qsetheaderlabels+-+set+column+headers+in+a+QTreeWidget) sets the headers for the columns in a QtreeWidget

Comment: It doesn't exist any method which permit to do this directly on the QTreeWidget ? And how can I modify the color of the title of the columns ?

Comment: investigate ctable https://geocap.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ref/ctable+-+Manipulate+Geocap%27s+color+tables